# Confusion about stress-energy tensor in 2D gravity when reformulated as a CFT

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm trying to verify that I obtain the same stress-energy tensor for a simple 2D gravity theory and the associated CFT reformulation. However, the results are not agreeing which leads me to believe I'm making a mistake in some step.

Take the following action
\begin{equation} 
S= \int d^2t \sqrt{-g} \left(\phi R\right) \,,
\end{equation}

with $R$ the Ricci scalar and $\phi$ a scalar field. If we vary this action w.r.t. $g^{\mu \nu}$ we obtain
$$
0=T_{\mu \nu} = \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi - \Box \phi g_{\mu \nu} \,,
$$
where I've used the fact that in 2D the Einstein tensor is zero. Then, taking $ds^2 = -e^{2 \rho} dt^+ dt^-$, we have, for example: 
$$
T_{+ +}= -2 \partial_+\phi \partial_+\rho +\partial^2_+ \phi\,, \\
T_{--} = -2 \partial_-\phi \partial_-\rho +\partial^2_- \phi\,.
$$
I would like to reproduce this result by first taking the ansatz for $ds^2$ and then computing the stress-energy tensor for the CFT. The action becomes
$$
S= \int d^2t \left( \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \rho  \right)\,.
$$
Under a conformal diffeomorphism $\xi= \xi^+(t^+)\partial_+ + \xi^-(t^-) \partial_-$, the scalar $\phi$ transforms as $\phi \mapsto \phi - \xi^\nu \partial_\nu \ \phi $. On the other hand, one can find the transformation of the field $\rho$ by looking at $\mathcal{L}_\xi g$, which leads to the conclusion that $\delta \rho = -\xi^\nu \partial_\nu \rho -\frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu \xi^\nu.$

Hence, using the fact that 
$$
\xi^\nu T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial^\mu \psi_a\right)} \delta \psi_a + \xi^\nu \eta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L} = \xi^\nu \left( -\partial_\mu \rho \partial_\nu \phi - \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \rho  +\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi + \eta_{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha \phi \partial^\alpha \rho \right)\,,
$$
where $\eta= - dt^+ dt^- $ and an integration by parts was performed on the $\partial_\nu \xi^\nu$ term.

Comparing this expression of the stress-energy tensor to the previous one, we see that they don't agree due to the factor of 1/2 on the $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu \phi$ term. Am I wrong in assuming that the two methods should yield the same stress-energy tensor or am I making some mistake?